# Creating geospatial app for both iOS and Android

Tags: web-mapping, software-recommendations, arcgis-web-appbuilder, development

Does anyone have any experience or solid foundation on how to build geospatial apps that can be utilized through app stores? Specially, I am searching for a way to present simple, publicly available data that can be scripted to auto update when the data from the source has been updated. I know ESRI has some type of web development platform, but I do not have experience with that portion of Arc (everything else I am very familiar with). I have some coding background, but would prefer a plug and play (no coding) interface such as bubble.io.

Any feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the ESRI's ArcGIS App Studio, which is a low-code platform for creating native apps. It allows you to quickly build apps for distribution in your organization or to publish to app stores.

[ArcGIS App Studio](https://youtu.be/eZDf4p_1dVE)